Why does this 4-week Treasury bill that I bought have a 17-week term and a much earlier issue date?
I submitted an order on Fidelity to purchase a newly issued 4-week t-bill. The order went through and I got a t-bill that matures in 4 weeks. However, after looking it up by CUSIP on treasurydirect.gov (link), I noticed that it was issued a few months ago and has a 119-day term instead.
Could someone please clarify what might be happing here? Did Fidelity purchase this bill on a secondary market instead of the newly issued bill?

You wanted a 4-week t-bill and you got a 4 week t-bill, what's the concern? Does it matter to you if it's a newly minted CUSIP, reissue of a previous series, or secondary market? Why?

@DStanley yes the CUSIP is correct, I bought the t-bill on June 20th.

@littleadv it doesn't really matter, but feels a bit misleading? It sounds like Fidelity might be charging me more than it costs them to buy these t-bills on a secondary market.

The other answer is actually misleading. No, Fidelity didn't sell you off-the-run bills. What you got is indeed a newly issued T-bill. There's a term for this: reopening.
https://www.treasurydirect.gov/auctions/reopenings/
Here's what happened

UST sold $60B of 912797KQ9 in Mar, as a 17wk bill expiring 7/23.
UST reopened and sold another $80B 912797KQ9 in May, as an 8wk bill. Same term. (This increased the total outstanding to $140B.)
UST reopened again and sold yet another $70B in Jun, this time as a 4wk bill. (Total outstanding is now $210B.) You bought some of those.


Fidelity may have sold you a bill that expires 4 weeks from your order date instead of a newly minted bill. It is not uncommon to trade "off-the-run" treasury bills that have identical yields as newly minted bills that mature on the same date.
However, looking for that CUSIP on TreasuryDirect shows bills of different "Security Term" with the same CUSIP. Since they all have the same maturity date and do not pay a coupon (you instead buy them at a discount), they are fundamentally equivalent. There should be no material difference in the yield you get from the bill you purchased and one that you would have gotten from TreasuryDirect or through another broker that had the same expiry date. US Treasury debt is incredibly liquid (trades a lot) so there's generally very little difference across brokers.
So it's entirely possible that you did get a newly-issued 4 week bill that has the same CUSIP (and pays the same amount) as one issued 2 months ago.
Put another way - investors should be agnostic about a bill that was issued 3 months ago and has one month until maturity and a newly issued bill that has one month to maturity. Otherwise one could buy the cheaper one, short the expensive one and get a risk-free profit ("arbitrage").

That makes total sense, thanks! A quick follow up: it looks like this CUSIP was recycled for t-bills of different maturities (one of them is the one I linked in the original message: https://www.treasurydirect.gov/auctions/auction-query/?cusip=912797KQ9). I thought CUSIPs supposed to be unique, are 17-week t-bills "become" 8-week and then 4-week t-bills as they get closer to maturity?

The terms of the bill (meaning just the maturity date since there is no coupon) and the CUSIP do not change, but you can buy it for roughly the same price as you could a new 4-week bill, so they are equivalent but nothing really changes about the bill itself.

That part makes sense, thank you. To clarify my question/comment above: why do t-bills of different maturities have the same CUSIP (https://treasurydirect.gov/auctions/auction-query/?cusip=912797KQ9)? Aren't CUSIPs supposed to be unique?

They all have the same maturity date and do not pay a coupon, so they are all fundamentally equivalent.  They were just issued at different times. You get the same amount back at the same time no matter which one you buy.

@A.Shultz I updated my answer based on your link.

Company shares of the same class, likewise will share the same CUSIP, even if the company sold/issued them years apart.

Last paragraph is questionable. The discrepancy in price between on-the-run and off-the-run exists and is driven by liquidity. It's not an arbitrage unless one considers liquidity risk non-existent.

Great answer and it goes a long way to understanding why the price of (existing) bonds rise when rates go down.

On the auction-query page if you click Show/Hide Columns (below the table) and tick Reopenings, it confirms that these were indeed reopenings (@A.Shultz)
